# FME Desktop - JSON Extractor Transformer Error

Tags: fme-form, json, fme-transformer

I have a workbench which takes a JSON file and uses the following transformers to parse the data: JSONFragmenter, JSON Extractor and a vertex creator.

I am getting warning errors in my translation log when writing to a PostGIS database. The errors are as follows:

> "JSONExtractor (JSONQueryFactory): The JSON query
> 'json["data"][geomaster_name][*]' contains an invalid index at column
> 14.  An index must be a non-negative integer, a quoted string, or a * (wildcard) character"

The source data is coming from a url here:
https://data2.unhcr.org/population/get/sublocation/root?widget_id=211460&sv_id=39&population_group=5081&forcesublocation=0&fromDate=1900-01-01

I'm not sure if this is the correct avenue, but I inspected my output from the JSON extractor and referenced line 14. Line 14 is as follows:

```
{"geomaster_name":"Paraguay","geomaster_id":7513,"geo_sv_id":"7513","admin_level":"Country","centroid_lon":"-57.5244140625","centroid_lat":"-25.20494115356912","lat_max":-18.242430491113,"lon_max":-51.88671875,"lat_min":-30.965801735895,"lon_min":-65.88671875,"source":"Government","date":"2020-12-31","month":"4","year":"2018","published":false,"sv_published":"0","individuals":"2531","name":"Paraguay","numChildren":"0","color":"#3c8dbc"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out - PostGIS needs to be written to lower case field names. I had my writer set to upper and lower case.